# How to limit strace `file` tracing to only /proc/*/mem?

Tags: strace

I'm `strace`ing a program with the following command:

```
strace -o /tmp/program.trace -e trace=ptrace,process,file -s 1000 -y program --arguments
```

This works almost perfectly except one thing: for file accesses I'm only interested in `/proc/*/mem`, while the above command prints all the file accesses. I've tried using `-P /proc` option, but it appeared that it 1) only limits tracing to this particular directory and not its contents, and 2) prevents any tracing of `ptrace` and `process` syscall sets.

How can I limit `file` syscall set to only `/proc/*/mem` files (without pre-defining any particular path), while retaining `ptrace` and `process` sets in the trace?

Comment: You could use `awk` or `grep` on `/tmp/program.trace` (or even output to some pipe using these)